# Starting activity as a Dialog with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I need to start Activity as a dialog. All framework is made on top of ActivityActionBar so there is no way to use `Theme.AppCompat`  or set activity in manifest to preform as a Dialog `"<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`. So I cant extend Activity.

The activity must behave as dialog and it has to be on top of previous activity. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

the dialog has to be invoked as intent...

Comment: U said any suggestion.. So i try. Have you tried Dialog dia = new Dialog(context you want for the dialog); dia.show(); ? I doesn't tested it just a suggestion ...

Comment: @Mike That would work, but the dialog has to be invoked as intent

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion.. Create a class extend activity give context and open class/activity with intent from where you want 2..

Answer (score 0):

Create an own DialogActivity which extends from Activity and give it

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.floatingactivity);
```

Read more about it here:

http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/